# How to create single EnvironmentObject instance in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I usually create EnvironmentObject like this

```
    class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var obsValue1 = false
        @Published var obsValue2 = true
    }
```

And use it into ton of views

```
struct Example1: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    //...
}

struct Example3: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    //...
}

struct Example3: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    //...
}
```

Is there any good practice to create a single member of EnvironmentObject and use it through the app?

Comment: Don't use `EnvironmentObject` in the first place. You can use proper dependency injection with `ObservableObject`, use that. `EnvironmentObject` creates hidden dependencies - you don't know what to inject from the call site. At the same time, not injecting an `EnvironmentObject` results in a runtime error rather than a compile time error with `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Would you show usage of `settings` in those ExampleX views?

Comment: @Asperi Yea! When I want to use any value of EnvironmentObject, I have to create an object instance for each View!  Is there any way to use it in multiple Views from single instance?

Comment: Since structs do not support inheritance what you want to achieve is not possible. You also cannot use classes for Views as it is not designed to work that way. Here is a great article on why: [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-swiftui-use-structs-for-views#:~:text=First%2C%20there%20is%20an%20element,part%20of%20the%20bigger%20picture).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of *once created - used everywhere*

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var userSettings = UserSettings()   // one instance
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: " + String(describing: userSettings.obsValue1))  // << usage
            Example2()
        }.environmentObject(userSettings) // << injected into all subviews !!
    }
}

struct Example1: View {
    // @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings // not needed as not used
                                                   // passed below automatically
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Example2()
        }
    }
}

struct Example2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value2: " + String(describing: settings.obsValue1))  // << usage
            Example3()
        }
    }
}

struct Example3: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    var body: some View {
            Text("Value3: " + String(describing: settings.obsValue1))  // << usage
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the question was how could he reduce his code duplication by not writing the following line: '@EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings' each time he needs to access global state but use it directly (as if you inherited it from a parent class) which is not possible currently in SwiftUI.